# Formatting Text in a Table in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tabular

I'm having issues creating a table that is dynamic to adjust to various results.

I've written a screen scraper to pull stocks from http://finance.yahoo.com and print the company name, it's symbol, and it's current stock price.

However the output looks like this:

```
 Microsoft Corporation MSFT 29.76

 Apple Inc. AAPL 396.77

 SPDR S&P 500 SPY 155.25

 Google Inc. GOOG 787.76
```

I want it to look like

```
Microsoft Corporation        MSFT      29.76

Apple Inc.                   AAPL      396.77

SPDR S&P 500                 SPY       155.25

Google Inc.                  GOOG      787.76
```

I just started wokring with Python yesterday and am using 3.3.1

My current code is as follows:

```
import re
import urllib.request
import cgi
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

price = [0,0,0,0]
namesList = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
stocksList = ["msft","aapl","spy","goog"]

def HTML():
    i = 0
    while i < len(stocksList):
        htmlPull = urllib.request.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+stocksList[i]+"&ql=1")
        htmlPull = htmlPull.read().decode('utf-8')
        regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_'+stocksList[i]+'">(.+?)</span>'
        pattern = re.compile(regex)
        price[i] = re.findall(pattern,htmlPull)
        htmlParse = BeautifulSoup(htmlPull)
        title = htmlParse.title.contents
        namesList[i] = title        
        i+=1

formatPrice(price)
formatStock(namesList)
formatOutput(namesList, stocksList, price)

def formatPrice(price):
    k=0
    while k < len(price):
        cleaner = str(price[k])
        cleaner = cleaner.replace("[","")
        cleaner = cleaner.replace("]","")
        cleaner = cleaner.replace("'","")
        price[k] = float(cleaner)
        k+=1

def formatStock(namesList):
    k = 0
    while k <len(namesList):
        capital = stocksList[k]
        capital = capital.upper()
        cleaner = str(namesList[k])
        cleaner = cleaner.replace("Summary for ", "")
        cleaner = cleaner.replace(":"," ")
        cleaner = cleaner.replace("- Yahoo! Finance'","")
        cleaner = cleaner.replace("['","")
        cleaner = cleaner.replace("]","")
        cleaner = cleaner.replace(";","")
        cleaner = cleaner.replace(capital, "")
        namesList[k] = cleaner;
        k+=1

    def formatOutput(namesList, stocksList, price):
        i = 0
        while i < len(price):
        capital = stocksList[i]
        capital = capital.upper()
        print(namesList[i],capital, price[i])
        print("")
        i+=1
HTML()
```

Have tried print ({0},{1},{2}.format (namesList, capital, price[i])), various types of {:<16} variations, etc. It seems to only affect one line and I'm trying to get it to think in terms of columns, or a table, or maybe a certain amount of space that the text and whitespace should fill. I'm not sure what exactly the solution is here, so I'm asking you all :)

As you can tell by my code, I'm pretty new to programming, so if there is a better way to do anything in this code, I'd be happy to listen to correction, advice, and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the width based on the longest item in the column.

In Python, you use `max` to find the largest of some group of things. So, outside the loop, you can do:

```
names_width = max(len(name) for name in namesList)
stock_width = max(len(stock) for stock in stockList)
```

Then, format each line like you said you tried:

```
print({0:{3}}  {1:{4}}  {2}.format(namesList[i],
                                   capital,
                                   price[i],
                                   names_width,
                                   stock_width))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! The only changes I made was to add +2 to both names_width and stock_width to space it out just a little more. Also in Python 3.3.1 I had to add apostrophes around the curly braces to get it to be in the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('{:<10}{:^20}{:>30}'.format("left","center","right"))

output:
   >>>        left         center          right  

{:> = space in pixles with arbitrary int}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).