# Aligning text in a table using string formatting with a loop inside a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm supposed to align some numbers in a table while using a loop inside a loop. It should look like this when it's done:

- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

What I've stared with is:

```
for i in range(1,10,1):
    for c in range(1,6,1):
        print(i, end='\n')
```

Though after running this it just prints them bellow each other. And replacing "\n" with "\t" doesn't help either. I've tried `.format` but with no success. Sorry if this seems very simple and that it should be stated somewhere but I can't find someone with the same problem or some chapter referring to this specific problem.

I did manage to do this table by using `while` like this:

```
i = 1
while i < 6:
    print("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n" , end='' '')
    i += 1
```

This is of course not the best way to do it, I just don't have the knowledge to do it in a smarter way.

Comment: *"with no success"* - what does that mean? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: _"after running this it just prints them bellow each other."_ Have you pasted your most up-to-date code into this question? Because when I run your code blocks, I don't see anything printed at all. I just get `IndentationError: expected an indented block` and `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` respectively. Please double-check that what you've submitted here is what you're actually running.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry for the confusion. I shouldn't have used `.format` anyways since it was not intended for the task.

Comment: @Kevin 1.I didn't paste the code containing my previous attempts but I will do until next time. 2. If my code got an error i probably typed something wrong or the code was just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have inverted loop ranges it should be:

```
for i in range(1, 6, 1):
    for c in range(1, 10, 1):
```

Second, in the inner loop you have to print c, not i.

The full code would be like this:

```
for i in range(1, 6, 1):
    for c in range(1, 10, 1):
        print(c, end=" ")
    print('')
```

If you want to code only one `for` loop you can:

```
for i in range(1, 6, 1):
    print( " ".join(map(str, range(1, 10, 1))) )
```

Comment: Now I understand that it was the invertion of the loops that caused the problem. The full code worked fine and also the one where you only coded one `for` loop though I have not used `.join` or `map` before so I did not use the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your loops are in the wrong order. As you write your code, you will get 10 rows with 6 numbers.
    Next, you can't print in the inner loop, because you will get just 60 rows. So you can store rows in some `temp` value inside first loop, and on each cycle of outer loop print it. Also, for more pretty code, you can use list comprehensions.

`for i in range(1, 10):
        print ' '.join([str(number) for number in range(1, 6)])`

Also, to perfect this, you can write it in 1 string of code, but this is more understandable.

Comment: Mmmmm ...., this looks pretty much like my answer, do you take your time for reading it?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen your post. It seems you posted while I was preparing mine :D

Comment: For text tables, try format instead of string concatenation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110230/formatting-text-in-a-table-in-python