# Forming a table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a program that imports a text file, calculates the test averages and then prints it into a table. I have been able to get everything to work except for the format of the table.

Here is how the table should look

Reading six tests and scores

```
TEST---------------SCORE                                                                   
objects------------88 
loops--------------95
selections---------86
variables----------82
files--------------100
functions----------80

Average is
```

I can't figure out how to get objects, loops, selections etc. to come right under each other on here. But that is how the table is supposed to be set up. I just can't get the scores to line up in the score column.

Here is my code.

```
def main():
    print('Reading six tests and scores')
    print('TEST\tSCORE')
    test_scores = open('tests.txt', 'r')
    total_score = 0
    counter = 0
    line = test_scores.readline()


    while line != '':
        name = line.rstrip('\n')
        score = int(test_scores.readline())
        total_score += score
        print(name, score, sep='\t')
        line = test_scores.readline()
        counter += 1

    test_scores.close()
    average_test = total_score / counter

    print('Average is', format(average_test, '.1f'))


main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Text in a Table in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110230/formatting-text-in-a-table-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `'{:-<20}{}'.format(test, score)` to left justify and pad to 20 chars with a '-':

```
def main():
    print('Reading six tests and scores')
    print('{:-<20}{}'.format('TEST', 'SCORE'))
    with open('tests.txt') as f:
        scores = {test.rstrip('\n'): int(score) for test, score in zip(f, f)}

    for test, score in scores.items():
        print('{:-<20}{}'.format(test, score))
    print('\nAverage is {:.1f}'.format(sum(scores.values()) / len(scores)))

>>> main()
Reading six tests and scores
TEST----------------SCORE
objects-------------88
loops---------------95
functions-----------80
selections----------86
variables-----------82
files---------------100

Average is 88.5
```

Note: I moved to using the `with` statement to provide appropriate handling of the file and constructed a dictionary of `{test: score}`. The `zip(f, f)` is a little trick to step through the file 2 lines at a time given that `test` and `score` are on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

Separating columns by tabs is probably a bad idea, as it's difficult to predict how many tabs will be needed. You can use print formatting instead, like this for instance:

```
print('{:20} {}'.format(name, score))
```

This prints `name` padded to 20 characters, then `score`. I'm assuming the `-` in your table are just spacing characters. If you want to get fancy, you could read the file once and find the longest `name` in say `max_name_length`, then do:

```
print('{:{}} {}'.format(name, max_name_length, score))
```

See the full details about format specification strings [in the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/string.html#formatstrings).